# Where can I find the SQL standard document?

Tags: sql-standard

Where can I find a legal copy of the ISO SQL 2008 standard?

Comment: You need to purchase it. I don't think you can get (the interesting parts) for free.

Comment: FYI, the current version is [*SQL:2023*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2023), officially known as ISO/IEC 9075:2023 "Information technology – Database languages – SQL". Sold by ISO: [Part 1](https://www.iso.org/standard/76583.html) for 194 Swiss francs (about 207 Euros or 223 USD), [Part 2](https://www.iso.org/standard/76584.html) for CHF 216, [Part 3](https://www.iso.org/standard/84803.html) for CHF 216, and so on through Part  16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official and final texts the ISO SQL standard are *not* available freely. Available only by purchase.

The drafts, otoh, are often no more than a google search away.  Google for SQL200n.zip and you should get pretty close.

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** No longer listed on [*Publicly Available Standards*](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html). Must be purchased.

---

The ISO SQL 2008 Standard document *ISO/IEC 9075-1:2008 Information technology -- Database languages -- SQL -- Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)* is now freely available from the [ISO website](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's only Part-1. The most valuable part is Part-2, where all DDL, DML and DCL statements are described.

Comment: @ypercube maybe they're still drafting Part-2? ¯(°_o)/¯

Comment: It looks like it is not freely available anymore: https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html.