# Where can I find the SQL-89 standard?

Tags: sql-standard

**This question is different but similar to this request [looking for SQL-86](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168595/2639)**.

SQL 1989 is almost 30 years old. Is this spec freely available anywhere. The standard does not have a Wikipage or the like?

The spec goes by

- ANSI X3.135-1989 Database Language - SQL With Integrity Enhancements
- ISO 9075-1989
- SQL-1989

The need for it came up while researching the question, [Does the SQL-1992 standard restrict naming identifiers to 18 characters?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204668/2639)

Comment: answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168595/where-can-i-find-the-first-standardization-of-sql-sql-86 ?

Answer (score 1):

This one looks like the document you are after (although French, not English, and not free)
https://iteh.it/catalog/standards/iso/7c7fa915-f99f-4ce9-8aa4-0e896d89ed84/iso-iec-9075-1989

Or this one seems to have English and Russian versions:
https://gostperevod.com/st-iso-iec-9075-1989.html

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolating from [the accepted answer of the related question seeking SQL-86](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274523/68127), we can craft the following query -

- [https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22National+Bureau+of+Standards%22+AND+subject%3A%22Public+administration+--+Data+processing%22&and[]=year%3A%221990%22&and[]=year%3A%221989%22&and[]=year%3A%221988%22&sort=-date](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22National+Bureau+of+Standards%22+AND+subject%3A%22Public+administration+--+Data+processing%22&and%5B%5D=year%3A%221990%22&and%5B%5D=year%3A%221989%22&and%5B%5D=year%3A%221988%22&sort=-date)

...the constituent parts being

- creator="National Bureau of Standards"
- subject="Public administration -- Data processing"
- year IN (1988,1989,1990)
- order by date_published descending

Sadly, SQL-89 is not found at this time, but a partial upload from 1990 appears to be available at https://archive.org/details/federalinformati1271nati. Hopefully the given query string will also capture the SQL-89 standard if and when it's indexed at archive.org

Answer (score -1):

[This what you are looking for?](https://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20INCITS%20135-1992%20(R1998))

Information Systems - Database Language - SQL (includes ANSI X3.168-1989) (formerly ANSI X3.135-1992 (R1998))
Defines the data structures and basic operations on SQL-data. Provides functional capabilities for creating, accessing, maintaining, controlling, and protecting SQL-data.

Comment: No, that's SQL:92, I'm looking for SQL:89 here. If that includes it, then yes it has what I'm looking for but it's also behind the Pay Wall and the SQL-92 is public so the -89 spec should be too http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Perhaps FIPS PUB 127-1 - https://archive.org/stream/federalinformati1271nati/federalinformati1271nati_djvu.txt

Comment: That adopts but doesn't include SQL-89. It references it externally.

Comment: You can see it here btw in PDF, https://archive.org/stream/federalinformati1271nati/